# Getting Error recompile with -fPIC although POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE flag is enabled

Tags: cmake, g++, java-native-interface, fpic

I am trying to link afinit_state.a library with my C++ project through cmake. But I am getting bolow attached error. My cmake file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(java_telemetry_wrapper)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(JNI)
set(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH "$ENV{JAVA_HOME}/include")
find_path(JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH jni.h ${JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})

set(JNI_LIBRARIES ${JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY} ${JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY})
set(JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS ${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH} ${JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2} ${JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH})
set(STATE_PATH "/home/poc/src/state/")
set(LOGGER_PATH "../../logger")

include_directories(${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${STATE_PATH} ${LOGGER_PATH} ${AFN_STATE_INC} ${AFN_LOGGER_INC})
link_directories(/opt/lib/)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED header/TelemetryWrapper.h src/TelemetryWrapper.cpp ../telemetry.h ../telemetry.cpp ../common.hpp)
set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "-lpthread" afinit_state "-lz")
```

I have tried my options which I could find on internet before posting this question. Alot of people are saying use **set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)** which I did but error is still persisting. Please help me to narrow down the issue, what is causing this problem.

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /opt//lib/libafinit_state.a(af_state_service.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /opt//lib/libafinit_state.a(StateSvcMsgQ.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /opt//lib/libafinit_state.a(StateSvcShmCtl2.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /opt//lib/libafinit_state.a(StateSvcShmCtl.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /opt//lib/libafinit_state.a(af_ss_agent_store.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /opt//lib/libafinit_state.a(af_ss_call_store.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /opt//lib/libafinit_state.a(af_ss_hashed_tbl.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /opt//lib/libafinit_state.a(af_ss_mega_store.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /opt//lib/libafinit_state.a(StateSvcMQ_Msgs.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /opt//lib/libafinit_state.a(StateSvcObjDefs.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/java_telemetry_wrapper.dir/build.make:99: libjava_telemetry_wrapper.so] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/java_telemetry_wrapper.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you enabled PIC in `afinit_state`?

Comment: You don't show it here but I think `libafinit_state.a` that needs to contain PIC code. Can you recompile that one?

Comment: It is `libafinit_state.a` library, which are noted in the **error message**, should be recompiled with `-fPIC`. This is how the error message should be interpreted. Since your CMake project doesn't build `libafinit_state.a`, then you cannot avoid the error by modifying your project.

Comment: got it, thanks for highlighting the issue guys. And I can't change afinit_state's CMake file but I can build that again. I assume there should be a way to pass the PIC code from cmd when we execute "cmake <path-to-make-file>" command?

Comment: @UmarTahir you can use `-DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=On` at the commandline when invoking cmake. Alternatively, you can also pass `-fPIC` to the `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` (or `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` if that project is in plain C).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0083.html#policy:CMP0083

"
CMP0083

New in version 3.14.

To control generation of Position Independent Executable (PIE) or not, some flags are required at link time.

CMake 3.13 and lower did not add these link flags when POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE is set.

The OLD behavior for this policy is to not manage PIE link flags. The NEW behavior is to add link flags if POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE is set:
"

IE try using a newer version of CMake